# How to set up RDP server for existing/local desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp, vino, x11rdp

I'm been able to set up `xrdp` server on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, using `xface4` without any issues. Standard solution starts a new X server on a new port with `xface`.

Nonetheless I'd much prefer connecting to my local X-server with my existing session (usually started by `lightdm`) and take over control from the local user, similar to `vino-server` with `vnc` protocol or `TeamViewer`. This is because when working form my office I prefer developing locally, but don't like restart all my programs (browsers, IDE, etc...) when connecting from home or from an other city. While `vnc` works easy with `vino-server`, it is much slower due to "only" using image compression. As I understand RDP understands and transmits actual components of the desktop, and also seems to be faster in practice.

Any way to configure this?

Are you aware of other solutions which are both fast and use the existing local desktop session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible with xRDP.  xRDP Software does not connect to the console session but rather start a new session.  This is the way xRDP is working.

Based on your comments/questions, indeed, a possible option to get access to the console session through a remote session is to use a software like VNC....

Hope this help
Till next time 
See ya

Comment: I'm afraid -- having played with this -- this is the correct answer!